# PostgreSQL: Bulk update having unique index

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with unique index on two fields, lane_id and position.

Now, I want to update row using this query:

```
UPDATE "teams_ticket" SET "position" = ("teams_ticket"."position" + 1) WHERE ("teams_ticket"."lane_id" = 1 AND "teams_ticket"."position" >= 0)
```

Which ends up with:

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "teams_ticket_position_bfcce9fa_uniq"
```

If I have more than one ticket.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Depends on your schema.  It sounds like you have a unique key constraint on a value you're incrementing, which would be a good place to start looking to fix.

Comment: @Makoto Yes, I know. I have and index (see first line of ticket). The thing is, shifting all tickets by one position should end up with valid situation (all lane_id - position pairs still unique). But it looks like they get moved one by one and then index is failing. Im wondering what is the correct way to solve this issue.

Comment: You need `deferrable` here.

Comment: @wildplasser Looks like this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks, I will try it later today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `deferrable` constraints (and actually defer them, temporally). Deferrable means that the constraints are not checked immediately (say: when the index-tuple is being rewritten) but at the end of the transaction (or statement), when all rows have been updated:

-- \i tmp.sql

```
CREATE TABLE positions
        ( seq SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
        , position INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE DEFERRABLE 
        );

INSERT INTO positions(position)
SELECT generate_series(1,10) gs;

BEGIN;
SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED;

update positions
SET position= position +1
WHERE seq <= 6 ;

SELECT * FROM positions ;

UPDATE positions SET position= position +1
WHERE seq > 6
        ;

SELECT * FROM positions ;

UPDATE positions SET position= position +1
        ;

SELECT * FROM positions ;

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Downvoter:please explain. (since this is thecorrect answer, IMnsvHO)

Comment: This is a correct solution. In general, the reason for a failure was that constraint was not *deffered*. What I've done in my case is:

ALTER TABLE .. ADD CONSTRAINT ... DEFFERABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED

Previously I didn't have last bit, DEFFERABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cursor to update them one by one.

```
DO $$
  DECLARE r record;
BEGIN
  FOR r IN SELECT lane_id, position FROM teams_ticket WHERE lane_id=1 AND position >= 0 ORDER BY position DESC
  LOOP
    UPDATE teams_ticket SET position=position+1 WHERE position=r.position AND lane_id=r.lane_id;
  END LOOP;
END$$;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```sql
UPDATE teams_ticket t
   SET position = q.position + 1
  FROM (
    SELECT lane_id, position
      FROM teams_ticket
     WHERE lane_id = 1 
       AND position >= 0
     ORDER BY lane_id, position DESC
  ) q 
  WHERE t.lane_id = q.lane_id
    AND t.position = q.position
```

Comment: This might work. Or it might not. The `ORDER BY` in the subquery is essentially useless; the optimiser might even ignore it.